# bwboundaries to get image borders

Tags: image, algorithm, matlab, image-processing, dicom

I used bwboundaries to get image borders. It returns integer values. But I need float pixels.(spatial pixels) how can I fix that?

```
clc
clear all
close all
grayImage= dicomread('diz');

subplot(1, 1, 1);
imshow(grayImage, []);

hFH = imfreehand();

binaryImage = hFH.createMask();

subplot(1, 1, 1);
imshow(binaryImage);

structBoundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
arrayBoundaries=cell2mat(structBoundaries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`interparc` function on the MATLAB Files Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34874-interparc).  For the first structure in `structBoundaries`, the output of `bwboundaries`:

```
px = structBoundaries{1}(:,2);
py = structBoundaries{1}(:,1);
N = 100;
pt = interparc(N,px,py,'spline');
plot(px,py,'r*',pt(:,1),pt(:,2),'b-o')
```